# AMSlideMenu, AMSlideMenuContentSegue hiding top of the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Xcode and Objective-C. I want to implement simple slide menu with AMSlideMenu. I've got one left menu, and I need to go to the logout screen by clicking on logout (AMSlideMenuContentSegue) from that. I don't want the menu there.

Hiding the button and disabling the panGesture is not a problem. I've added:

```
// used for disabling gesture for menu and disabling left button
[self disableSlidePanGestureForLeftMenu];
[self removeLeftMenuButton];
```

But I still can see some layer above the top of my view. How could I get rid of that ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an answer for you. However, this question is certainly not related to xcode. You could, if you want, write your code on windows using notepad. Or edlin or vi or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using AMSlideMenu :)

If you mean how to hide navigation bar, then in your view controller, where you want to navigate by tapping on logout,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // If you want to bring back when this view controller is disappearing
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Or, basically, in storyboard select the navigation controller that holds your view controller, and set the "Top Bar" to "None"

[image]